# Tikz element above an EXISTING figure (beamer)

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am struggling placing tikz element above an existing figure (with caption) placed in a beamer presentation.

I want an overbrace and an arrow appearing in my presentation above my previous figure.

I couldn't find any answer except by placing my figure directly inside tikz environment.

Is there any solution ?

Thank you.

edit: edit code

```
 %\documentclass[draft]{beamer}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib} %before babel ?
\bibliographystyle{apalike_perso}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsubsection*{\bibname}}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
% other packages
\usepackage[justification=centering,font=tiny]{caption}
\captionsetup{width=0pt}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,xcolor,multicol,booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx,listings,stackengine}
\graphicspath{{figures}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{pifont}  %symbols library (usefull for item or arrows




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%SHOW AND USE BOXES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[absolute,showboxes,overlay]{textpos}     % déclaration du package
\textblockorigin{0mm}{0mm}                               % origine des positions
\TPshowboxestrue                                     % affiche le contour des textblock
\TPshowboxesfalse                                    % n'affiche pas le contour des textblock

%TIKZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
%\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
% \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
% \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
% \usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.footprints}

\usepackage{animate}



\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setcounter{figure}{1}}% Resets subfigure counter at start of figure environment
%\setcounter{figure}{1}

%mycaption
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{
\begin{center}
{\fontsize{5pt}{3.5pt}\selectfont
        {\textit{ \textcolor{deepblue}{{\textbf{ Fig. \alph{figure}:}} \textcolor{gray!95}{ #1}}}}
%        }
\par}
\end{center}  
 \stepcounter{figure}
}

%myenvironment for myfigure below
%\newenvironment{mc}[1]{\begin{center}  #1}{\end{center}}
%\newenvironment{ml}[1]{\begin{flushleft}  #1}{\end{flushleft}}
%\newenvironment{mr}[1]{\begin{flushright} #1}{\end{flushright}}
%myenvironment for myfigure below
\newenvironment{mc}{\centering  }{\par}
\newenvironment{ml}{\raggedleft }{\par}
\newenvironment{mr}{\raggedright}{\par}
%myfigure
\newcommand{\myfigure}[4]{
\begin{#1}
\begin{minipage}{#2cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=#2cm]{#3}
\mycaption{#4}
\end{minipage}
\end{#1}
}
\newcommand{\ifig}[1]{\addtocounter{figure}{#1}} %add to counter manualy


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[b]{mytitle}
\onslide<1->{
\begin{textblock*}{4cm}(20mm,15mm)
\ifig{0} {%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
\fbox{\myfigure{mc}{4}{example-image-a.png}{IP vs EM}}
}
 \end{textblock*}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,x=1cm,y=-1cm,shift={(current page.north west)}]
\draw<2->[ultra thick,color=red, ->] (4.75,1.925) .. controls (6,1) and  (7.25,2)  .. 
(7.25,2) .. controls (7.25,3.5) .. (8,3.5);
\draw<2->[thick,color=red,decorate,decoration={brace}] (3.9,2) -- (5.6,2) node[above,pos=0.5] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Hello thank you, I edited the code for a minimal compilation

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem,... nothing to see with tikz and includegraphics.

This was the textblock fault, Textblock environment overlays everything in the frame if I understood well. As I place my figures inside textblock they appear in the "top layer" (over my tikz elements)

To solve the problem I put my tikz environment directly in the textblock environment as follow :

```
\begin{textblock*}{4cm}(20mm,15mm)
\onslide<1->{\ifig{0} \myfigure{mc}{4}{IPvsEM.png}{IP vs EM}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,x=1cm,y=-1cm,shift={(current page.north west)}]
\draw<2->[ultra thick,color=red, ->] (4.98,1.8) .. controls (6,0.9) and  (6.8,.9)  .. 
(7,2.5) .. controls (7,3) .. (8,3);
\draw<2->[thick,color=red,decorate,decoration={brace}] (4,1.9) -- (5.6,1.9) node[above,pos=0.5] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{textblock*}
```

Bye

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).